# AIX: a hotspare hdisk not changing the status to rebuilding

Tags: aix

Using AIX 5.3 with TL12  I have configured a hdisk as hostspare in one vg. When I pulled a disk from the same vg it shows missing but the hotspare will never goes to rebuilding state. Your help in this is highly appreciated